# Open Graph Diagram

Tags: c#, facebook-opengraph

Everyone I am fresh programmer want to integrate my project with facebook Open Graph Diagram.

I have some doubt about it is possible to set up individual object by programming instead of going to register in https://developers.facebook.com/apps one by one?

For example: If I am a retailer shop that having more than 500 items, that will be very time consuming to register all of items by manually. Therefore is there any alternative solution for this?

Any helps will be appreciated. =)

Answer (score 1):

The objects you register in the Facebook settings pane are actually object types. Once you define an object type, such as "product", you can use all of your pages under the "project" object by adding the metatag

-Tassilo